What is the continuous product



Two
Many
Continuous




+
$\sum$
$\int$


*
$\prod$
What goes here?



What goes in the missing box, and what do I search to learn more.
If there is no single symbol, a larger formula will work instead (probably involving limits or integrals)
PS: If anyone has a better suggestion for the correct tags, please put it a comment or edit

How about $\exp \int \ln$?

@Pranay how will the $\text{exp}$ and the $\ln$ nullify each other?

@MathGuy I don't understand what you mean by nullify. I am defining a continuous product as $\exp \int \ln$. There are several other definitions as discussed in the link in the answer below.

@Pranay nullify in the sense of inverse functions, $e^{\ln x}=x\forall x>0$. Here, after integration, applying the exponential doesn’t make sense to me as to how it’d be a continuous product.

@MathGuy it’s definition makes sense and it is a possible generalisation, replace continuous by discrete

@MathGuy It might be helpful to think about it this way. If $P$ is the "continuous product," then using simple rules of logarithms we have the log of the product is the sum of the logs, so we can "solve for $P$" like so: $\ln P = \int \ln$ implying $\exp(\ln P) = \exp(\int \ln)$. So $P = \exp(\int \ln)$. This is neither rigorous, nor a proof, but hopefully the suggested definition makes more sense.

@JohnCavanaugh ah thanks, now I get it!

The formula $P=\exp(\int\ln)$ only works if we product integrate positive numbers. If we instead integrate operators (e.g. matrices) then the product integral is more interesting. For example, the solution to $U'(t)=A(t)U(t),$ where $A$ and $U$ are matrices, can be written as a product integral: $$U(t)=P_0^t e^{A(s),ds},U(0).$$

See Product integral. Apparently there is not a single definition but several that follow the same idea.
